# LAPACKE C++ Real Matrix Inversion

Tags: c++, matrix, lapack, matrix-inverse, lapacke

I am trying to invert a real matrix in C++ LAPACKE. I have the same function for complex matrices and it works. But the real case gives the wrong answer. Here's my function:

```
void inv(std::vector<std::vector<double>> &ans, std::vector<std::vector<double>> MAT){

    int N = MAT.size();

    int *IPIV = new int[N];

    double * arr = new double[N*N];
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<N; j++){
            int idx = i*N + j;
            arr[idx] = MAT[i][j];
        }
    }

    LAPACKE_dgetrf(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, N, N, arr, N, IPIV);
    LAPACKE_dgetri(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, N, arr, N, IPIV);

     for (int i = 0; i<N; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<N; j++){
            int idx = i*N + j;
            ans[i][j] = arr[idx];
        }
    }

    delete[] IPIV;
    delete[] arr;
}
```

I tried inverting a 24 by 24 matrix of doubles. While the program seems to be almost there, the inverse is not quite there yet and it differs a lot from what python linalg inverse gives me (python is right here because I multiplied the matrix with inverse and result is very close to indentity). In the LAPACKE output, I multiply the matrix by its inverse and I get the diagonals being 1 but the non diagonals go to values up to 0.17, which is huge compared to 0. Is there a way to make the LAPACKE program to give a better result? Thanks!

Comment: Is it well-defined matrix? What is the value of matrix determinant?

Comment: 2.2864066779666567e+37. It has large values so I think that's why the program is having trouble?

Comment: Yes, that might explain the effect. You could try to multiply input matrix (each term) by (1/25), which will decrease determinant by factor of 25^{-24}=2.8e-34 (if I'm not mistaken), thus making input matrix determinant about 1000. Then compute inverse and multiply back by 1/25. I've put simple python code in the answer

Comment: Taking a look at the source of numpy's `linalg.inv()`, in particular line 1555 - 1693 -1727 of [umath_linalg.c](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src), it solves A.X=Id, using dgesv() instead of calling dgetrf() and dgetri(). Scipy makes use of dgetrf() / dgetri(). Could you try to use scipy's `scipy.linalg.inv()` in python and see if it also result in a correct output?

Answer (score -1):

For matrix with large determinant you could rescale input, compute inverse and then rescale output back. Here is very simple Python example, your scale factor should be 1/25 or so in order to get total multiplier of (1/25)<sup>24</sup>=2.8e-34, thus making input matrix determinant about 1000.

```
import numpy as np

scale = 0.5

i = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
print(i)
print(np.linalg.det(i))
print("-----------------------------------")
x = np.multiply(i, [scale]) # rescale matrix
print(x)
print(np.linalg.det(x))     # determinant should be less
print("-----------------------------------")
y = np.linalg.inv(x)
print(y)
print(np.linalg.det(y))
print("-----------------------------------")
o = np.multiply(y, [scale]) # rescale matrix
print(o)
print(np.linalg.det(o))
print(np.dot(i, o))
```

You could play with the `scale` and verify that whatever value is code returns properly inverted input matrix.

So your code would be

```
double scale = 1.0/25.0;

for (int i = 0; i<N; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<N; j++){
        int idx = i*N + j;
        arr[idx] = scale*MAT[i][j];
    }
}

....

for (int i = 0; i<N; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<N; j++){
        int idx = i*N + j;
        ans[i][j] = scale * arr[idx];
    }
}
```